# Google.colab is not working with anaconda throws an error ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: anaconda, google-colaboratory, drive, google-drive-shared-drive

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCZWH.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jg5pY.jpg)

Please tell me relevant solution how to run Google colab file on anaconda

Remove the error of ModuleNotFoundError google.colab
As it is not picking up the Google drive link which is having file. Project is correctly running in the Google Collab.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "colab file", it is just regular Jupyter Notebook. The `google.colab` package is specific to Google Colab, you can't install it using `conda` or `pip`. If you want to upload/download files from Google Drive, you can use an alternative library such as [PyDrive2](https://github.com/iterative/PyDrive2).

Regarding your package installation error in the attached screenshot, the error is not caused by the Anaconda environment, it is probably because of incompatible package version with Windows. Try installing your dependencies in Linux or WSL 2 (since Colab runs on Linux machine).